# Mobile phone simulation WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i have to write simple mobile phone simulator, simple keyboard and LCD with couple of options in menu.

My question is:
Is it worth to implement here a MVVM pattern?
What would be the best way to show different LCD states? Make a couple of grid (LCD) styles and switching it, depends on what button would be clicked? Or changing each control contained in grid?

Comment: Apparently, the simple mobile phone simulator turns out to be a little more complicated than anticipated.

Comment: I do not want to compile aplications on that simulator, this should only respond to keyboard action with changes on LCD, no special options etc.

Comment: You have at least two, more likely three or more questions in your problem. My advice would be to do some thinking about the problems you're facing, work them out as far as you can, and then pose the remaining ones as clear, concise, and answerable questions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create the actual simulation engine first, then think about the graphical parts, so yes, a pattern like MVVM would be a good idea.
Depending on your "LCD" size, a grid would be a bad idea - you want to use picturebox or alike.
Also you might want to use a scripting engine like Lua to write the simulated stuff.

How flexible should it be?

Pen and paper really help in the early design phases.

Comment: Engine? This should be something like this: Menu>Call>SMS>Options>Music when you chose Options, new text occurs on LCD, when you chose SMS, LCD should look like SMS window, but there is no need to support any action. This project is only to show what are this particular model options and how you can slide through   menu.

Comment: Then you should really go with a picturebox and just load static images. I was confused because you said simulator.

Comment: the case is that there are no graphics elements in menu, only text. Maybe changing labels properties would be better solution? I suppose big amount of pictures to load in picturebox would make app heavier or im wrong?

Comment: My point was simply that functionally it's not a simulator, but more of a slideshow. Why bother talking about pixels or lcd states if all you want to show is text?